# Update all the elements of a list without loop

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have a list, `Arraylist<User>`. The User object has field `active`. I need to update all the user objects of the list with the active field as `false`.

Iterating through the list, I can update the field value. I want to know if there is any other way, using which I can update all the objects active field to 'false'?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Basic thing, without iterating how can you access and update it's contents ?

Comment: I dont have the object to set it into the list,  I only want to update a field of the User Object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For java 8 you can use the stream API and lambdas

```
List<User> users;
users.forEach((u) -> u.setActive(false));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think, I will g with this. This is also a form of for loop, but this reduces the no. of lines.

Comment: @YaduKrishnan I wouldn't worry about reducing the number of lines, I'd be more concerned about making the code as easy to understand as possible. In this case I think the lambda syntax achieves that, but my point is that, in general, using more lines to express something is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, i have to do this in more than one list. Currently, i have to do the similar code in 4 lists. In this case, the number of lines increases drastically.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 8, you can use the [`Iterable<E>.forEach(Consumer<? super E> action)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method as follows:

```
users.forEach((user) -> user.setActive(false));
```

Otherwise you'll have to use the standard enhanced-for loop approach:

```
for (User user : users) {
    user.setActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using Java8, and can use 3rd party libraries, take a look at the Collection2.transform() function in the [Google Guava](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava) library

Below is an example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<Boolean> myList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        myList.add(true);
        myList.add(true);
        myList.add(true);
        myList.add(true);
        myList.add(true);

        System.out.println(Collections2.transform(myList, new Function<Boolean, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(Boolean input) {
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }));
    }//outputs [false, false, false, false, false]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for functional programming and Java 8. You could do something like this:

```
users.forEach(user -> user.setActive(false))
```

If you don't use Java 8, there are similar libraries such as [LambdaJ](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)